# Trouble persisting one-to-many relationship using jpa in Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, spring-mvc, jpa

I have two entities as below and when i try to persist "Category" the "Tip" object list does not get persisted .I noticed that in my DAO class that I was able to see the category object with tipsForCategory list of size 1 but when i try to retrieve after persisting I am able to see only Category details and tipsForCategory comes as empty list.

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    public Long id;

    @Column
    public String categoryName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category",cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public List<Tip> tipsForCategory;


    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public String getCategoryName() {
        return categoryName;
    }

    public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
        this.categoryName = categoryName.toLowerCase();
    }

    public void addTip(Tip tip) {
        if(!tipsForCategory.contains(tip)) {
            tipsForCategory.add(tip);
        }
    }

    public List<Tip> getTipsForCategory() {

        return tipsForCategory;
    }



}
```

Code for Tip Entity

```
@Entity
public class Tip {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Key key;

    @Column
    public String tipDescription;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    public Category category;


    public String getTipDescription() {
        return tipDescription;
    }

    public void setTipDescription(String tipInformation) {
        this.tipDescription = tipInformation;
    }



}
```

Code for persisting in my DAO

```
 @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Category category) {
         EntityManager localEntityManager=entityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
         EntityTransaction transaction=localEntityManager.getTransaction();
        try {
            transaction.begin();
            localEntityManager.persist(category);
            localEntityManager.flush();
            transaction.commit();

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            localEntityManager.close();
        }


    }
```

My retrieval method is

```
@Override
    public CategoryDTO findCategory(Long categoryId) throws FixitException{

        CategoryDTO categoryDTO=null;
        Category category=categoryDAO.findById(categoryId);
        if(category!=null) {
            categoryDTO=new CategoryDTO(category);
        }
        return categoryDTO;


    }

 @Override
    public List<TipDTO> retrieveTips(Long categoryId) throws FixitException{

       List<TipDTO> tips=null;
        try {
            CategoryDTO category = findCategory(categoryId);
            if (category != null) {
                tips = category.getTipsForCategory();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
           throw new FixitException(FixitConstants.TIP_RETRIEVAL_ERROR+categoryId,e.getCause());
        }

        return tips;

    }
```

Comment: so you go on about a problem in retrieve, yet haven't posted the code for retrieving (or say where you are checking the collection) or what state the object is in

Comment: retrieveTips() code as above is the one i had used for retrieval in my service and the category.getTipsForCategory() was returned as null

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem was with lazy fetch I just resolved the same.In my categoryDAO.findById(..) code I had to add an additional line to retrieve the tips as below

```
@Override
    public Category findById(Long categoryId) {

        Category category=null;
        try {
            TypedQuery<Category> findByCategoryId = entityManager.createQuery("Select cat from Category  cat where cat.id=:categoryId",Category.class);
            category=findByCategoryId.setParameter("categoryId", categoryId).getSingleResult();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        *** int tipsSize=category.getTipsForCategory().size();***
        return category;

    }
```